# Does Google Cloud Spanner support VIEWS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Couldn't find it in the Cloud Spanner documentation, does anyone that's used it know if it supports SQL Views?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it doesn't. Views are in the backlog.

Answer (score 0):

As of [20-Aug-2021](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/release-notes#August_20_2021), Views are supported in Cloud Spanner

The syntax is

```sql
{ CREATE VIEW | CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW } view_name
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
AS query
```

[More information in the Cloud Spanner Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/views).